# ListView and size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have xml listview. How I can change its height in activity? 
I know that this code:

> list.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 600));

means that my listview will have 200 width and 600 height, but how can I change only height in activity? I want do this because I want to width fill parent but height my list I want my own and dynamically counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if width is `FILL_PARENT`

**list.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,600));**

```
or
```

width is `WRAP_CONTENT`

**list.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,600));**

Comment: calling list.invalidate() afterwards might be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 600));
```